# Django обновление страницы с сервера

Tags: javascript, python, django

Добрый день. Предположим, есть два юзера. Один жмет кнопку на сайте, второй же сразу видит без обновления страницы сообщение "юзер 1 нажал кнопку". Посоветуйте, как реализовать? Каждую секунду-две запрашивать состояние кнопки юзера 1 аяксом?

Comment: Возьмите за основу любой из чатов которые реализуют WebSocket и посмотрите как устроено.

Answer (score 1):

Существует несколько способов сделать так, чтобы один пользователь видел изменения на страничке, сделанные другим пользователем. Общая модель называется [Comet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)). Реализация возможна различными способами, например:

1. [Long polling](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-longpoll).

Заключается в том, что браузер, устанавливает соединение с сервером (используя XMLHttpRequest), ожидая того момента, когда клиент захочет передать что-то серверу. После получения данных от клиента, соединение закрывается и сразу же создается новое соединение. Веб-сервер должен поддерживать данный способ.

2. [WebSocket](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets)

Это бескостыльный способ реализации самых настоящих сокетов в вебе.

Следует отметить, что используя только `django`, ни один из указанных способов вы применить не сможете, поскольку `django` обрабатывает каждый запрос синхронно и первое же polling-соединение подвесит ваше `django` приложение. Для организации comet-сервера можно посмотреть отличный асинхронный `python` web-framework [`tornado`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/), который поддерживает и long polling и WebSockets.

Comment: Можно ли использовать сокет на js? https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#пример-браузерного-кода
Например сделать просто сайт на джанго двухстраничный. Одна страница - юзер 1, вторая - юзер 2. На клиентах открываем сокеты на прием и отправку. А ip юзеров для сокета просто пересылаем с ответом сервера, просто извлекая из request

Comment: `django` работает по принципу _получил запрос_ -> _обработал_ -> _отправил ответ_. Любая задержка в этой цепочке и все остальные клиенты будут ждать. Чисто теоретически вы можете организовать асинхронную работу с сокетами даже в `django`, но, думаю, даже не представляете, какой это будет ад в реализации и поддержке. Так что ни в коем случае так делать не советую. Для comet-сервера нужно использовать что-то, помимо `django`, тот же `node.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите django-channels. https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
Добавляет поддержку Websocket в джанго.

Автор: Andrew Godwin 
В следующих версиях джанги channels обещают добавить в стандартную поставку.